# How to configure Castle Windsor Extension for .Net 7 Dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, .net-7.0

I have a .Net 7 WPF application that is using Castle Windsor and where all my registrations are already setup.
I'm looking to use the .Net Dependency injection and re-use the container code I already have using [this extension](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Castle.Windsor.Extensions.DependencyInjection/5.1.2/)
The goal is to be able to easily register additional libraries that already have extensions for the .net host (MediatR, Serilog...). Most of these libraries aren't esay to register in Castle.

My issue is that I cannot figure out how to use this extension... The [documentation](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/net-dependency-extension.md) I found seems very vague and I cannot relate it to how I am supposed to plug it in the .Net builder.
I don't understand teh sequence of event and how i re-use the Windsro registration code I already have in `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseWindsorContainerServiceProvider()`.
Do I need to pass an already configure container ? Do I register after?
Quite confusing...

Thank you for your help.